# Column Headers printed after each row in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, datatable

I'm trying to make a simple Flutter app which fetches data from Firebase and displays it in a DataTable widget. The problem I'm facing is that the column headers (eg. Name, Phone) are being "printed" after each row. I wish to fix that. Below is the code I have so far. Please ignore the commented code. Thanks.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sub_mgmt/page/addnewpage.dart';
import 'package:sub_mgmt/page/data/users.dart';
import 'package:sub_mgmt/page/model/user.dart';

class SortableTable extends StatefulWidget {
  const SortableTable({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  State<SortableTable> createState() => _SortableTableState();
}

class _SortableTableState extends State<SortableTable> {
  // Sorting functionalities
  // late List<User> users;
  // int? sortColumnIndex;
  // bool isAscending = false;

  // Reading data from firebase
  CollectionReference _referenceMembers = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> _streamMembers;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // users = List.of(allUsers);
    _streamMembers = _referenceMembers.snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _streamMembers,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = snapshot.data;
            List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> listQueryDocumentSnapshot =
                querySnapshot.docs;

            // Original
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listQueryDocumentSnapshot.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  QueryDocumentSnapshot document =
                  listQueryDocumentSnapshot[index];
                  return Member(document: document);
                });
          }
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddNewPage()));
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        elevation: 4.0,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}


 
class Member extends StatefulWidget {
  const Member({
    Key? key,
    required this.document,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?> document;

  @override
  State<Member> createState() => MemberState();
}

class MemberState extends State<Member> {

  final columns = ['Name', 'Phone'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: const [
        DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Phone')),
      ],
      rows: [
        DataRow(
            cells: <DataCell>[
              DataCell(Text(widget.document['Name'])),
              DataCell(Text(widget.document['Phone'].toString())),
            ]
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here's what it looks like now

[image]

I'm aware that the DataTable widget is being built repeatedly but I'm unable to find a way around it.

Comment: can you check your `FirebaseFirestore` console if it is having theses fields as value `Name,phone` as text, if so, you need to remove theses

Comment: try `final data = querySnapshot.docs.last.data() as List?; ..  itemCount: data?.length,` and I think you should pass the data on `Member` to generate the all rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterating each Member in the ListView, and each Member has

```
columns: const [
  DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
  DataColumn(label: Text('Phone')),
],
```

Why don't you move this DataTable outside the ListView

```
DataTable(
  columns: const [
    DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Phone')),
  ],
  rows: rows, // Your list of DataRows 
);
```

And create your List of DataRows, each DataRow is like a Member

```
List<DataRow> get rows => listQueryDocumentSnapshot.map((element) => 
  DataRow(
    cells: <DataCell>[
      DataCell(Text(element['Name'])),
      DataCell(Text(element['Phone'].toString())),
    ]
  )).toList();
```

*I don't think you even need the ListView.builder

This is enough

```
DataTable(
  columns: const [
    DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Phone')),
  ],
  rows: listQueryDocumentSnapshot.map((element) => 
    DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text(element['Name'])),
        DataCell(Text(element['Phone'].toString())),
      ]
    )).toList();
);
```